# app crashing when ever i remove number digits.(contents in text field) in android

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi there I am working on a requirement, I have two edit text(text fields) if I enter 1 in the first text field it will increment and display 2 in the second text field.

I am getting the functionality but the problem is when ever I enter a digit and try to remove it by pressing back space its crashing.

I want to set zero when everything is removed from the first text box.

This is the code.

My **xml** code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Input Text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myTextBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="After Calculation" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/outputBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />
```

My java code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.type2);
    final EditText outputTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.outputBox);
    final EditText myTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myTextBox);
    myTextBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            String inputs = myTextBox.getText().toString();
            int i = Integer.parseInt(inputs);
            i++;
            outputTextBox.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for null or empty string. `try` and `catch` blocks help there:

```
try {
    String inputs = myTextBox.getText().toString();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(inputs);
    i++;
    outputTextBox.setText(String.valueOf(i));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Invalid integer received (empty or null string)
    outputTextBox.setText("");
}
```

Explanation:

`Integer.parseInt` throws a `NumberFormatException` if null or empty string is passed. If that is the case you just clear the `outputTextBox`.

Solution 2:

Manually check for an empty string as suggested by @rossum.

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputs)) {
    outputTextBox.setText("");
} else {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(inputs);
    i++;
    outputTextBox.setText(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Comment: Try/catch is slow.  Better to check for an empty string and skip the parse.  Just put another empty string in the output box instead.

Comment: @rossum oh, never heard that try/catch is slow. Any sources for that so I could read on?

Comment: @user3249477 See Bloch Effective Java (2nd edition) Ch 9, Item 57.

Comment: @rossum Thanks for providing an exact source! I'll definitely look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the **onTextChanged** as follow:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
    String inputs = myTextBox.getText().toString();
    if(inputs.isEmpty())
        outputTextBox.setText("0");
    else{
        int i = Integer.parseInt(inputs);
        i++;
        outputTextBox.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I need to put zero if it's empty as you explained me.